# TcpClientConnect() freezes UI

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, progressdialog, blocking

I want to create a program in which the user connects to a specific PC with a TcpClient socket and meanwhile show the user a loading spinner.

I've set the SendTimeout of the socket to 10 secs- this is the period of time that I want the ProgressDialog to be shown. At the end of the 10 secs (or before- if the socket successfully creates a connection with the other side), I want to dismiss the Dialog.

The problem is that Connect() blocks the UI from updating, results in not showing the ProgressDialog.

```
TcpClient tc = new TcpClient{SendTimeout = 10000};
pd = new ProgressDialog(Activity);
pd.SetTitle("Trying to connect PC");
pd.SetMessage("Loading...");
pd.SetCancelable(false);
pd.Show();

tc.Connect(some_ip, some_port);

pd.Dismiss();
```

PS: I'm using XAMARIN.

Please Note:

1. I have already tried to call Connect() in a seperate thread.
2. I have already tried to use AsyncTask in order to show the dialog, yet I'm not sure that I did it right.

Comment: You must move your socket code to a worker thread, it doesn't belong in the UI thread. Besides, Android does not allow you to use sockets in the main UI thread to begin with. You should be getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` error at runtime.

Comment: It actually worked in the UI thread. So your suggestions is the run the Connecr function in a background thread?

Comment: [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException) says: "*[NetworkOnMainThreadException] is thrown when **an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread**. This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, **but it's heavily discouraged**.*"

Comment: So, my suggestion is to run ALL of your socket code in a background thread, in all versions. [Google even says so](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr).

Comment: Is AsyncTask ok?

Comment: yes. Did you not read the documentation I linked to? "*The most effective way to create a worker thread for longer operations is with the AsyncTask class.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Links don't work on phone. Thank you!

Comment: they work fine on my phone. I posted them from my phone to begin with

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is there any application? I use Chrome.